# Why does my Meteor template rendered callback not fired when using sub-manager?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am not sure if this is related to the subs-manager package I am using: https://github.com/kadirahq/subs-manager

But whenever I navigate between routes that do not load any data from the server, the rendered callback for the template does not get called.

This is a big issue because I have all the functions that are supposed to run when the template is rendered.

So Meteor removes the template from the DOM, and when it renders it back it does not call the rendered callback. Why? This is a huge issue for me.

Comment: When I remove the subs caching the rendered callback is fired each time. Why is caching the subscriptions preventing the rendered callback from firing. This is not good design.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this if you do not include a minimal example that shows this behaviour.  I'd recommend using http://meteorpad.com/